# Replace Email with blank in a string || Redshift

Tags: sql, string, sql-update, amazon-redshift

We have a table in redshift, and a column that contains email address. How to replace the email address with blank?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a simple `update` statement:

```
update mytable set emailid = null
```

This sets `emailid` to `null` on all rows of the table. If there are many rows where that column is `null` alread, a `where` clause might speed things up:

```
update mytable set emailid = null where emailid is not null
```

If you want to set the value to the empty string instead of `null`:

```
update mytable set emailid = '' where email is not null and email <> ''
```

Note that this last statement requires `emailid` to be of a string datatype.